# Explaining MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Some days ago I asked here for a solution to retrieve a query which gets values from two diferent tables. The question was asked quite fast, thanks to this awesome community here... But continuing: I used the query and it worked perfectly, but I don't understand it. The query is following:

```
SELECT e.*, u.Username 
FROM Entries AS e 
LEFT JOIN Users AS u ON u.ID = e.User 
WHERE e.Category = 'SomeCategory' 
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Can anyone explain what each "step" of the query does? 
"WHERE","LIMIT","SELECT" and "FROM" I know, but the others get quite complicated for me.

Thanks

EDIT: `LIMIT 10,0` changed to `LIMIT 0,10`. I written it the wrong way... Sorry about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT e.*, u.Username 
FROM Entries AS e 
LEFT JOIN Users AS u ON u.ID = e.User 
WHERE e.Category = 'SomeCategory' 
LIMIT 10, 0;   -- are you sure about it???
```

How it works:

1. Get `Entries` table and "rename" it to `e` (add alias)
2. Get `Users` table and "rename" it to `u`
3. Join (outer) both tables based on `ID` column from `Entries` and `User` from `Users`
   (for non matched rows from Users set `NULL`)
4. Filter out records that value in `Category` column is equal `'SomeCategory'`
5. Skip first 10 rows and get 0 rows
6. Show every column from `Entries` and `Username` column from `Users`

**Warning**

Without explicit `ORDER BY` you can get different resultsets between executions. Why you want to return empty resultset **`LIMIT offset, row_count`**?

**EDIT:**

After your edit 5. should be **Skip first 0 rows and get 10 rows**

`LIMIT 0, 10` is the same as `LIMIT 10`

Comment: *"and rename it to e"* - It's more like "*and use it as an alias"*. ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- `rename` can be misleading, aliasing yes

Comment: Sorry, I switched the last two numbers... It's 0,10